# My render shows the grease pencil on the front and backside of my 3d object (x rays right through the 3d object

Tags: rendering, materials, eevee-render-engine

Why do my lines show through from the back of the object? I delete the default cube; add a sphere; add a grease pencil; go into draw mode; press 1 for front mode; get the ink pen; push the strength to 1; write on the front face and go around to the back of the sphere and write on it.[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had this problem for a few days as well, finally got it to work by checking the "z" checkbox under Data under Passes in view layer properties. [Heres the reddit thread i found the answer in if this doesnt work or you need additional info](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/ikpo7i/grease_pencil_objects_are_overlapping_everything/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks!  It worked.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't working for me in 3.60.  Instead, I found this:

N Panel: Annotations   (mine is pinned, it might be under Item tab?)

There are two icons for each layer: overlapping squares, and eye.
Click the overlapping squares so the front square becomes opaque.

[image: N Panel: Annotations: Grease Pencil X-Ray display Icons]